# Please verify this proof that there are Infinitely many binary functions on N that satisfy these conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

**THEOREM**

There are infinitely many binary functions on $\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy the following conditions, and they differ **only** in the value assigned to $f(0,0),$ namely $x_0$ here.

(1) $~~f(n,0)=\begin{cases} x_0,  & \text{if $n = 0$} \\ 1, & \text{if  $n\neq 0$} \end{cases}$

(2)  $~~f(n,m+1) = f(n,m)\times n$

**PROOF**

The proof is a trivial exercise filling in a table of values for function $f$.

**Row $0$**

Just keep multiplying by $0$.

$f(0,0) = x_0~~$ (applying (1) with $n=0$)

$f(0,1) =  x_0\times 0 =0~~$ (applying (2))

$f(0,2) = 0 \times 0 = 0~~$ (applying (2))

and so on.

$
    \begin{array}{|l|l l l l l }
        \hline
        f      & 0      & 1      & 2      & 3      & \cdots \\ \hline
        0      & x_0    & 0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots \\ 
        1      & ~      & ~      & ~      &       & ~ \\ 
        2      & ~      & ~      & ~      &       & ~  \\ 
        3      & ~      & ~      & ~      &       & ~  \\ 
        \vdots & ~      & ~      & ~      &       & ~  \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
$

---

**Column $0$**

Keep applying (1) with $n\neq 0$.

$
    \begin{array}{|l|l l l l l }
        \hline
        f      & 0      & 1      & 2      & 3      & \cdots \\ \hline
        0      & x_0    & 0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots \\ 
        1      & 1      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~ \\ 
        2      & 1      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~  \\ 
        3      & 1      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~  \\ 
        \vdots & \vdots      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~  \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
$

---

**Row $1$**

Just keep multiply by $1$.

$f(1,1)=f(1,0)\times 1 =1\times 1 =1~~$(applying (2))

$f(1,2)=f(1,1)\times 1 = 1\times 1 = 1~~$ (applying (2))

$f(1,3)=f(1,2)\times 1 = 1\times 1 = 1~~$ (applying (2))

And so on.

$
    \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        f      & 0      & 1      & 2      & 3      & \cdots \\ \hline
        0      & x_0    & 0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots \\ 
        1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & \cdots \\ 
        2      & 1      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~ \\ 
        3      & 1      & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~ \\ 
        \vdots & \vdots & ~      & ~      & ~      & ~  \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
$

---

Row $2$

Just keeping multiplying by 2.

$f(2,1)=f(2,0)\times 2 =1 \times 2 =2 ~~$(applying (2))

$f(2,2)=f(2,1)\times 2 = 2\times 2 = 4~~$ (applying (2))

$f(2,3)=f(2,2)\times 2 = 4\times 2 = 8~~$ (applying (2))

And so on.

$
    \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        f      & 0      & 1      & 2      & 3      & \cdots \\ \hline
        0      & x_0    & 0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots \\ 
        1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & \cdots \\ 
        2      & 1      & 2      & 4      & 8      & \cdots \\ 
        3      & 1      & ~      & ~      &~      & ~ \\ 
        \vdots & \vdots & ~ & ~ & ~  & ~ \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
$

---

**Row $3$**

Just keeping multiplying by 3.

$f(3,1)=f(3,0)\times 3 =1 \times 3 =3 ~~$(applying (2))

$f(3,2)=f(3,1)\times 3 = 3\times 3 = 9~~$ (applying (2))

$f(3,3)=f(3,2)\times 3 = 9\times 3 = 27~~$ (applying (2))

And so on.

$
    \begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        f      & 0      & 1      & 2      & 3      & \cdots \\ \hline
        0      & x_0    & 0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots \\ 
        1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & \cdots \\ 
        2      & 1      & 2      & 4      & 8      & \cdots \\ 
        3      & 1      & 3      & 9      & 27      & \cdots \\ 
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
$

---

Two things should (?) be obvious about the function $f$:

1. $x_0$ can be any natural number.
2. Apart from $f(0,0)$, all other values of $f$ are independent of the value assigned to $f(0,0)$.

Clearly (?) then, there are infinitely many binary functions on $\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy the given initial conditions, but they differ **only** in the value assigned to $f(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written down isn't actually a *proof*, really - nor have you stated your *goal* precisely. That said, the right idea is there.

Here is how I would set things up:

> **Theorem**: for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is exactly one function $f:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $$(*)_k:\quad f(0,0)=k,\quad f(n+1,0)=1,\quad f(n,m+1)=f(n,m)\times n$$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

*Proof sketch*: Fixing $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we need to prove *existence* and *uniqueness*. Existence is easy; uniqueness we prove by induction. Suppose $f,g$ both satisfy $(*)_k$ but $f\not=g$. Then there must be some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a,b)\not=g(a,b)$ but for all $(c,d)$ with $c\le a,d\le b$, and $(c,d)\not=(a,b)$ we have $f(c,d)=g(c,d)$. It's easy to show that both $a$ and $b$ must be nonzero, but then we can get a contradiction by thinking about $(a,b-1)$.

Note that the careful statement of the result more-or-less tells us how the rigorous proof will go.

Comment: Thanks, Noah. I have formal versions of these proofs including uniqueness, but would like to make them more accessible.

Comment: (+1) In defense of my informal argument (if not technically a proof), do you not find it convincing that such a function does exist AND, apart from the value of $f(0,0)$, is also unique? Have I overlooked some possibilities that need to be nailed down?